# WPF binding of property with multiple usercontrols level

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I have two usercontrols (LoginView.xaml and DashboardView.xaml).
DashboardView.xaml is placed inside LoginView.xaml .
Now, my objective is initially DashboardView should be invisible and on login success it should be visible and the controls in stackpanel "loginSP" should be invisible.

LoginView.xaml is as follows :-

```
<UserControl x:Class="DashboardModule.LoginView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DashboardModule"
         xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Matrix.Infrastructure.Framework.Utility;assembly=Matrix.Infrastructure"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="loginUC"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"  Background="Pink">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter"></converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel Margin="200">
    <StackPanel x:Name="loginSP">
        <TextBlock Text="Dashboard" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbUserName" Height="25" Width="300" ></TextBox>
        <PasswordBox Margin="2"></PasswordBox>
        <Button Content="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text,ElementName=tbUserName}"  Width="200"
            ></Button>
    </StackPanel>       

    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border >
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Template>
        <local:DashboardView  Visibility="{Binding DashboardVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </ContentControl>       

</StackPanel>
```

DashboardView.xaml is as follows :-

```
<UserControl x:Class="DashboardModule.DashboardView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DashboardModule"
         xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Matrix.Infrastructure.Framework.Utility;assembly=Matrix.Infrastructure"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Background="BlanchedAlmond" x:Name="DashboardUC"
         Visibility="{Binding Visibility,ElementName=rootGrd}">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter"></converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid  x:Name="rootGrd" ToolTip="{Binding MyName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
       Visibility="{Binding DashboardVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>          
</Grid>
```

My LoginViewModel.cs is as follows :--

```
private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    public DelegateCommand<string> LoginCommand { get; set; }           
    public DashboardViewModel DashborardVM { get; set; }
    public LoginViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        DashborardVM = new DashboardViewModel();
        LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Login, IsValid);
    }

    private void Login(string obj)
    {
        DashborardVM.MyName = "My Name After Login";
        DashborardVM.DashboardVisible = true;
        //this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ShellLayoutChangeEvent>().Publish("anindya");
    }

    private bool IsValid(string param)
    {
        if (param.Length > 0)
```

My code of DashboardViewModel.cs is as follows :-

```
private bool _dashboardVisible;
    public bool DashboardVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return _dashboardVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            _dashboardVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DashboardVisible");
        }

    }
    private string myName;
    public string MyName
    {
        get
        {
            return myName;
        }
        set
        {
            myName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyName");
        }
    }

    public DashboardViewModel()
    {
        MyName = "anindya";            
    }
```

Now the output is : 
1.Initially DashboardView is invisible .
2. On login success DashboardView is not getting visible although I am setting DashborardVM.DashboardVisible = true; on my loginviewmode.cs.

I am using Prism design pattern. 
the following way I am registering the views and viewmodel.

```
public class ModuleDashboardModule: IModule
{
    IUnityContainer _container;
    IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public ModuleDashboardModule(IUnityContainer container,
                                IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _container = container;
        _regionManager = regionManager;

    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _container.RegisterType<ILoginView, LoginView>();
        _container.RegisterType<ILoginViewModel, LoginViewModel>();
        _container.RegisterType<IDashboardView, DashboardView>();
        _container.RegisterType<IDashboardViewModel, DashboardViewModel>();

        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.DashboardRegion,
                                                typeof(LoginView));
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.DashboardRegion,
                                                typeof(DashboardView));
    }
}
```

this is my bootstrapper.cs class :--

```
public class BootStrapper : UnityBootstrapper,IDisposable
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
        App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

        Type moduleAType = typeof(ModuleDetailsModule);
        Type moduleNewForm = typeof(ModuleNewFormModule);
        Type moduleToolbarType = typeof(ModuleToolbarModule);
        Type moduleFooterType = typeof(ModuleFooterModule);
        Type moduleDashboardType = typeof(ModuleDashboardModule);
        Type moduleInvestmentType = typeof(ModuleInvestmentModule);
        Type moduleInvestmentDetailsType = typeof(ModuleInvestmentDetailsModule);

        ModuleCatalog.AddModule
        (
            new ModuleInfo()
            {
                ModuleName = moduleAType.Name,
                ModuleType = moduleAType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable
            }

        );
        ModuleCatalog.AddModule
        (
            new ModuleInfo()
            {
                ModuleName = moduleNewForm.Name,
                ModuleType = moduleNewForm.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable
            }

        );

        ModuleCatalog.AddModule
        (
            new ModuleInfo()
            {
                ModuleName = moduleToolbarType.Name,
                ModuleType = moduleToolbarType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable
            }

        );

        ModuleCatalog.AddModule
        (
            new ModuleInfo()
            {
                ModuleName = moduleFooterType.Name,
                ModuleType = moduleFooterType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable
            }

        );

        ModuleCatalog.AddModule
        (
            new ModuleInfo()
            {
                ModuleName = moduleDashboardType.Name,
                ModuleType = moduleDashboardType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable
            }

        );

        ModuleCatalog.AddModule
            (
              new ModuleInfo()
              {
                  ModuleName = moduleInvestmentType.Name,
                  ModuleType = moduleInvestmentType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                  InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable
              }
            );

        ModuleCatalog.AddModule
            (
            new ModuleInfo()
            {
                ModuleName = moduleInvestmentDetailsType.Name,
                ModuleType = moduleInvestmentDetailsType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable
            }
            );
    }
```

My LoginView.xaml.cs file is :

```
public partial class LoginView : UserControl,ILoginView
{
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public LoginView(LoginViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public IViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return (IViewModel)DataContext;
        }
        set
        {
            DataContext = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My DashboardView.xaml.cs is as follows:

```
public partial class DashboardView : UserControl,IDashboardView
{
    DashboardViewModel viewModel = new DashboardViewModel();
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public DashboardView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
        //this.ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public IViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return (IViewModel)DataContext;
        }
        set
        {
            DataContext = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting where I am making mistake . Any help is appreciable .

Comment: Can some moderator tell me why someone can directly give negative vote to my question ? Is it wrong to ask question or there is any crime to ask a question or my question is not proper ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to avoid handling Visibility too much in a ViewModel.
Instead, expose a bool e.g. LoggedIn and bind to it in your View.
There you can use a Style/DataTrigger to change Visibilies accordingly.

```
<Style x:Key="LoginVisibilityStyle" TargetType="StackPanel">
     <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoggedIn}" Value="false">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoggedIn}" Value="true">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
          </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

if you have to go for a different Controls DataContext i.e. ViewModel, you can do this:

```
="{Binding DataContext.LoggedIn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:MainView}}}"
```

Comment: Although I was not looking for an answer with trigger but yes as it is working so accepting this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about setting the correct data context.

Seems you are not setting the datacontext for the dashboard view. Therefore the loginViewModel becomes the datacontext of the dashboardview. This is because the datacontext is inherited from the xaml's parent control if not set explicitly.

Try setting the data context for content control

```
    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding DashborardVM}">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Grid>
                <Border >
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
    <local:DashboardView  Visibility="{Binding DashboardVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</ContentControl>
```

Otherwise you will have to make all the bindings in the format

```
{Binding DashborardVM.DashboardVisible}
{Binding DashborardVM.property}
```

EDIT -
By the way if you are using prism please check whether the viewmodel is correctly registered so they get automatically assigned.
And probably setting the visibility as

```
<local:DashboardView  Visibility="{Binding DashborardVM.DashboardVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

will help because here the datacontext is LoginViewmodel

Comment: I have tried your both options . 1.<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding DashborardVM}"> and 2. {Binding DashborardVM.DashboardVisible} but it is not working . It is actually hitting the setter of the property DashboardVisible in DashborardVM but getter section is not getting hit. 
Moreover I am using prism. I have updated the question with viewmodel register code sections.

Comment: You seem to have 2 DashBoardViewModel instances (one in dashboardview.xaml.cs and other in loginviewmodel.cs). And that seems to make the problem. One easy fix I can suggest is remove all the visibility related code from dashboardviewmodel and move dashBoardVisible property to LoginViewModel. Once you have the dashBoardVisible property in LoginViewModel, you can easily remove the DashboardViewModel instance from LoginViewModel. And also I think looking at the debug output in visual studio will show you what are the binding errors.

Comment: I have removed DashboardVisible property to LoginViewModel and bind directly to usercontrol like (<local:DashboardView  Visibility="{Binding DashboardVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}"/>). still it is not working.